# Android Retrofit consuming API not working

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm working on an Android project and I'm using retrofit to fetch JSON data. My JSON look like this.

```
{  
       "status":"ok",
       "count":1,
       "count_total":1,
       "pages":1,
       "posts":[  
          {  
             "id":4,
             "type":"post",
             "slug":"my news",
             "status":"publish",
             "title":"test news title goes here",
             "title_plain":"test news title goes here",
             "content":"<p>news title goes<\/span><\/p>\n",
             "date":"2018-05-12 20:00:51",
             "modified":"2018-05-12 20:00:51"
          }
       ]
    }
```

My model class -Article.java

```
public class Article {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;

@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;

@SerializedName("title_plain")
@Expose
private String titlePlain;

@SerializedName("content")
@Expose
private String content;

@SerializedName("date")
@Expose
private String date;


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getTitlePlain() {
    return titlePlain;
}

public void setTitlePlain(String titlePlain) {
    this.titlePlain = titlePlain;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

}

I'm calling to retrofit method like this and already added a dialog box for loading. But I'm not getting response from the API. (It works perfectly when I'm typing on the browser)

```
       NewsService service = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(NewsService.class);
    Call<List<Article>> call = service.getNewestArticles();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Article>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Article>> call, Response<List<Article>> response) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            generateDataList(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Article>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });


   private void generateDataList(List<Article> articles) {

    lstNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    lstNews.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


    adapter = new ListNewsAdapter(articles,getActivity().getBaseContext());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lstNews.setAdapter(adapter);

    lstNews.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I'm new to retrofit. Could someone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: go to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and paste the JSON there and generate the JAVA class. You should have same thing. You are expecting `List<Article>` but it's inside another JSON so you should have something like `ArticleResponse` which has `List<Article>`

Comment: I created this model class from jsonschema2pojo. Why do I add ArticleResponse?

Comment: Why do I add ArticleResponse? --> Because that's how your JSON response is. Just try it and see. I suggest you to do the manual JSON parsing first so you understand how the data is parsed and then switch to Retrofit with GSON.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually loading a list (array) of articles but an object conatining a list of articles, so you need 2 model classes :

```
public class ArticleResponse {
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;

    @SerializedName("count")
    @Expose
    private int count;

    @SerializedName("count_total")
    @Expose
    private int countTotal;

    @SerializedName("pages")
    @Expose
    private int pages;

    @SerializedName("posts")
    @Expose
    private List<Article> articles;

    //getter/Setter
    //...
}
```

Your retrofit service should return that ArticleResponse instead, then you can get your article array through `articles` getter from your model

```
NewsService service = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(NewsService.class);
    Call<ArticleResponse> call = service.getNewestArticles();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArticleResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArticleResponse> call, Response<ArticleResponse> response) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            generateDataList(response.body().getArticles());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArticleResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.w( t );
        }
    });
```

Comment: private List<Article> articles; In here after that do I need to create new class as 'Ariclte' and add geters setters for that?

Comment: Just keep your Article model as well, only `ArticleResponse` is missing from your code

Comment: I already added getArticles method in article response.But I'm gettng error cannot resolve method getArticles @Samuel Eminet